# Replace Parameter value in unix

Tags: text-processing

Trying to write a shell script which can replace the parameter reading from parameter file

input file :

```
param1 = abc
param 2= wer
```

I need to replace the `abc` and `wer` value with `xyz` (for both `param1` and `param 2`)

`xyz` is value which I need to place in the property file which shell script can read and replace in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to stream the edit into the file.

```
sed -i "s/param1=.*/param1=abc/g"
```

This replaces the line with `param1=xyz` (or any literal, via the dot and asterisk regex) with `param1=abc`.

Comment: Also, in Bash scripts, variable declaration cannot have spaces in between (like in your example).